# C++: tag/trait template: ensure tag is bound only once

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

The title is probably too vague, I'll explain what I mean.

I am developing a helper library for working with TLV encoded values. In the library, each value holds a tag id, tag type code and tag value in proper native type. Such tagged value container is implemented by a template class parametrized on tag id and associated type trait (which declares properties of the tagged value) . Now I want to be able to ensure that one tag ID is only associated with one trait, so that I couldn't create TLV values with same tag ids but different data types. So this is a kind of tag vocabulary, only checked at compile time.

```
template<uint_t TagId, typename Trait>
struct TagBinder
{
    enum { my_id = TagId };
    // stuff skipped
};
```

I want to make sure `TagBinder<100, IntTrait>` and `TagBinder<100, BoolTrait>` will not compile together. I wonder if this is possible at all. Is there something in boost MPL maybe that I could use? One thing that I am trying to avoid is macros. Also, C++11 is out of the question unfortunately.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you have multiple translation units and each unit can instantiate a different set of binders, there is no way (Besides you have an overall unit including all binders).

Comment: How about encoding the traits as a specialization of a class templated by Tag, i.e., `template <uint_t> struct TagTraits {}; template <> struct TagTraits<100> { /* IntTrait */ }; template <uint_t TagId> struct TagBinder { typedef TagTraits<TagId> Trait; };`? Specializing `TagTraits` twice for the same tag value becomes an ODR violation, diagnoseable if in the same TU.

Answer (score 0):

So I have to admit there is no answer to my question. There seems to be no way to achieve what I want in pure c++.